# Building LAN with android phone (Xiaomi Redmi 3s)

Tags: wi-fi, usb, reverse-tether, lan

I am trying to build a LAN using my phone. Have connected the phone via USB to the pc and switched on WiFi hotspot (so i can connect laptop, printer etc to the Internet). But i cant get them together, as i know my public IP provided by IPS, i cant get the local IP for my PC, and other gadgets as well. And my phone is not connected to any WiFi hotspots, as i use it as a hotspot itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "get them together"? What's the LAN configuration you're trying to achieve, and what do you need the public IP for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more information, I can help you.
The APP [ES file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=de) provides a LAN function.
If you want to route over the PC to a router or something do this.

1.)First, you need to enable [routing](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-IP-Routing.).(Windows)

2.)You need an app that provides you with a terminal (terminal emulator etc.)

```
Example:
ifconfig usb0 192.168.0.2
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
```

Set your DNS server :

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

or with BusyBox:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

3.)Under Windows you need to configure the path to your router.

```
route ADD 192.168.0.2 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
```